# Java Exception getOutputStream() has already been called for this response while downloading file from backend

Tags: spring, file, download, java-8

I have this code in order to download files from backend:

```
    final File file = new File(filePath);
    String fileType = Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());
    response.setContentType(fileType);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition: attachment;", "filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    response.setContentLength((int)new File(filePath).length());

    final OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(is, os);
    response.flushBuffer();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
```

and I get this exception in backend:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:578)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212)
```

Does anyone know what I can do in order to prevent this exception?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you shouldn't call `flush` and/or `close` on the response outputstream
Other way would be to delegate all to Spring controller
I always use this code and I never had problems

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, 
                value = { "/file/{idFile}" })
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadCsv(
                        @PathVariable("idFile") String idFile) {
    try {
        File file = new File("yourFilePath");
        HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        //Add your mediaType....mine was csv
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text","csv");
        respHeaders.setContentType(mediaType);
        respHeaders.setContentLength(file.length());
        respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", file.getName());

        InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String message = "Errore nel download del file " 
                         + idFile + ".csv; " 
                         + e.getMessage();
        logger.error(message, e);
        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I hope this can be useful

Angelo